# Truncating float to the two first non-zero decimal digits

Tags: java, floating-point

I want to truncate floating point numbers in Java up to the two first non-zero decimal digits. For example, `0.000134` to `0.00013`, or `11.00401` to `11.0040`.

The only solution I can think of is to strip the integral part, and multiply by 10 until I get a number bigger or equal to 10. Then truncate the original float up to `number of multiplications` decimal digits.

But I might have to do this operation often, so I'm looking for a faster solution.

My test code:

```
public static String truncateTo2NonZero(double f) {
    int integral = (int)f;
    double decimal = f - integral;
    int digits = 0;

    while (decimal < 10) {
        decimal *= 10;
        digits++;
    }

    double ret = (int)decimal / Math.pow(10, digits);
    ret += integral;

    return Double.toString(ret);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    final int TESTS = 1000000;
    double[] floats = new double[TESTS];

    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < TESTS; ++i) {
        int zeros = random.nextInt(6) + 3; // divide by 10^zeros
        double digits = random.nextInt(100) + 100; // 3 last digits
        floats[i] = digits / Math.pow(10,zeros) + random.nextInt(20) + 1;
    }

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < TESTS; ++i)
        truncateTo2NonZero(floats[i]);
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();

    long duration = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println(duration / 1000000); // in milliseconds
}
```

I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit. Output of `java -version`:

```
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a dupe of those. OP here wants to have a dynamic number of decimals, i.e. retaining up-to the two first non-zero decimal digits.

Comment: @copeg Not duplicate. It's like Tunaki says. I think it's pretty clear from the two examples I gave.

Comment: "floating point" "decimal digits"  These two phrases should never appear in the same sentence.  You should be using `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you want to "truncate" this sounds like a display format. That being said floats are not friendly for this. BigDecimals are. This should give you a start, needs error checking of course.

```
static String roundToLastTwoDecimalDigits(float f) {
    // split whole number and decimals
    String[] floatParts = new BigDecimal(f).toPlainString().split("\\.");

    int wholeNumberPortion = Integer.parseInt(floatParts[0]);

    // count zeroes
    String decimalPortion = floatParts[1];
    int numDecimalPlaces = 0;
    while (decimalPortion.charAt(numDecimalPlaces) == '0')
        numDecimalPlaces++;

    // get 3 digits to round
    String toRound = decimalPortion.substring(numDecimalPlaces,
            numDecimalPlaces + 3);

    int decimalForRounding = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(toRound) / 10);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append(wholeNumberPortion);
    sb.append(".");
    for (int i = 0; i < numDecimalPlaces; i++)
        sb.append("0");
    sb.append(decimalForRounding);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Just tested, and this is slower. 3703 milliseconds compared to 538 for my way, for 500k random floats.

Comment: @devil0150 `BigDecimal` isn't meant to be fast, it's meant to be correct.

Comment: @devil0150 Can you share your code? I am thinking of an algorithm, much like Compass's but is less intense computationally. To make sure we're comparing apples to apples however, share your code to factor the time and method you're generating the random numbers out. Also, let us know your machine/JVM specs.